# Negative number of confirmations for a testnet transaction on blockexplorer

Tags: testnet, confirmations, blockexplorer, blockcypher

I am curious about the test transaction f72f59a32c1bac47ec87bc3678ec44e98eece5e235d29d79cd1f5461ccc5bf38. Depending on which site I view this transaction, the number of confirmations is positive or negative:

On https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/f72f59a32c1bac47ec87bc3678ec44e98eece5e235d29d79cd1f5461ccc5bf38 there are -1797 confirmations.

However on https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/f72f59a32c1bac47ec87bc3678ec44e98eece5e235d29d79cd1f5461ccc5bf38 there are +1318 confirmations.

Moreover, one of the outputs appears to be spent on blockcypher but unspent on blockexplorer.

I have two questions:

- Why is there such a difference in the number of confirmations?
- Is there something wrong with this transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely on blockexplorer.com, you will notice that the site does mention that the transaction was included in block #1484064. The blockexplorer seems to be confused about the height of the blockchaintip, or has some other general issues regarding the confirmation count. For example, it shows all of the transactions in the latest block to have -3562 confirmations: [image: Blockexplorer.com showing transactions in last block with -3562]

The transaction in question has some 1300+ confirmations, so this seems to be squarely on blockexplorer.com.